# REACT -> problems with yarn start via GitBash or VS Code terminal

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I've got a problem with localhost when running `yarn start`. It seems that everything is okay, but my web page is blank when it opens. Should be at least the React logo. I am using windows 10.

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view my-app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://...............:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

Comment: Not clear, are there error in console ? Is it working from regular command line  ?

Comment: would you please add the code of your app.js file? or snippet?